# File allocation size issue: Size on disk larger than expected

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems

I have formatted and set the allocation unit size of my usb thumb drive (NTFS, 512B). However, when I copy small (several KB) files to the drive, they take up 32KB of size on disk... I have lots of small files so want to minimise lost space.

Is there something I'm missing? I thought the size on disk would be the smallest multiple of the allocation unit size that is larger than the file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, doing a "Quick format" didn't seem to change the allocation unit size. A full format did the job.